# Can't use the same DisposableObserver with subscribeWith twice after dispose()

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

The code (Kotlin) is very simple, but I don't understand, why I can't use the same object to subscribe again?

```
val x = Observable.interval(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
    .map {
        println("emitting=$it")
        it.toString()
    }.publish().autoConnect()

val o = object : DisposableObserver<String>() {
    override fun onComplete() {}
    override fun onNext(t: String) = println("O:=$t")
    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {}
}
println("---------- subscribe ----------")
val s2 = x.subscribeWith(o)

sleepSeconds(2)
println("---------- dispose ----------")
s2.dispose()

sleepSeconds(2)
println("---------- subscribe again ----------")
x.subscribeWith(o) //<<-- This doesn't work!!!!

sleepSeconds(5)
```

The console output is:

```
---------- subscribe ----------
emitting=0
O:=0
emitting=1
O:=1
---------- dispose ----------
emitting=2
emitting=3
---------- subscribe again ----------
emitting=4
emitting=5
etc.....
```

It works well, when I create a new instance of class DisposableObserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DisposableObserver` is designed to only able subscribed once [javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/DisposableObserver.html). When you look under hood of DisposableObserver, you will see AtomicReference `upstream` which saving current disposable when observer subscribing.

```
public abstract class DisposableObserver<T> implements Observer<T>, Disposable {

    final AtomicReference<Disposable> upstream = new AtomicReference<Disposable>();

    @Override
    public final void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
        if (EndConsumerHelper.setOnce(this.upstream, d, getClass())) {
            onStart();
        }
    }
// rest of code
```

`EndConsumerHelper.setOnce`  make sure DisposableObserver subscribed only once. If `upstream` has been disposed, then no other `upstream` could be set.

```
public static boolean setOnce(AtomicReference<Disposable> upstream, Disposable next, Class<?> observer) {
        ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(next, "next is null");
        if (!upstream.compareAndSet(null, next)) { 
            next.dispose();  // dispose next if there is set upstream previously 
            if (upstream.get() != DisposableHelper.DISPOSED) {
                reportDoubleSubscription(observer);
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;  
    }
```

That's why you cannot resubscribe with same DisposableObserver instance, but will work using new instance.